# How to use charAt() properly when I am checking if a word is palindrome in Java?

Tags: java

For simple words as "madam", "madama" etc., the code is working but for longer Strings like "babzsákfotelben sok a bab" returns wrong answer.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String A = sc.nextLine();

        String myString = A.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", "");
        int i = 0;
        int j = myString.length() - 1;

        while (i < j) {

            if (myString.charAt(i) != myString.charAt(j)) {

                System.out.println("No");
                break;

            }

            i++;
            j--;

            System.out.println("Yes");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem in your current code is that your loop only executes once because after incrementing `i` and decrementing `j`, you print "Yes" and break out of the loop.

What you should do is declare a boolean variable that is initialized with the value `true`. Inside the loop, in any iteration, if the `if` condition evaluates to `true`, set that boolean variable's value to `false` and break out of the loop.

After the loop ends, check if the value of the boolean variable is still `true`. If it is, then string is a palindrome, otherwise its not.

```
int i = 0;
int j = myString.length() - 1;
boolean isPalindrome = true;

while (i < j) {
    if (myString.charAt(i) != myString.charAt(j)) {
        isPalindrome = false;
        break;
    }

    i++;
    j--;
}
    
if (isPalindrome) {
   System.out.println("Yes");
} else {
   System.out.println("No");
}
```

Comment: Or, even simpler: Ditch that variable, `return false;` when the chars aren't equal, and after the while loop, `return true`. Roll the initialization of `i` and `j` into a basic for initializer, and the whole thing boils down to a 2-liner.

Comment: @rzwitserloot yes that is a better way to do it but for that to work, code should be inside a separate function and OP will have to check the return value of the function and then print "Yes" or "No" depending on the return value of the function. Instead of suggesting a different approach, i only wanted to address the problem in OP's current code.

Comment: Thanks @Yousaf for the clear and short answer. I just made the other way when I use a function for that approach. And in the main I just call the function. Now I have two working version :)

Answer (score 1):

**What you can do is instead of using a while loop, you can use for loop, and instead of a string, you can use StringBuilder. Here's how it goes:

**

```
public class Palindrome {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Creating an instance of scanner class
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Creating an instance of StringBuilder class
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    //Asking for input
    System.out.println("Please Enter the Word: ");
    //Getting Input
    String word = scan.next();

    /*
     *
     * Palindrome Check
     *
     */

    for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        str.append(word.charAt(i));
    }
    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(String.valueOf(str))) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }

}
```

}